# Trying to list items in object and one is an array....keep getting error

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I have tried other answers to questions listed on here and they do not work. What am i doing different?

I have an app where I want to list a topic that has a list/array of comments associated with it.  When a user clicks on the "add topic" link, the user will then see a random topic generated with past comments associated with it and also an opportunity to add a new comment.  I can print out the topic but I can not print out the comments. I can even print out the comments in the console but not on the page.  The error says the comments are undefined.  What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

topic.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createComment, listTopicWithComments } from '../util/APIUtils';
import './Topic.css';
import TopicComp from '../components/TopicComp';
import { Form, Input, Button, Icon, Select, Col, notification } from 'antd';
const URL='http://localhost:8080/api/auth/randomtopic';
const URL2='http://localhost:8080/api/auth/topic/';
const Option=Select.Option;
const FormItem = Form.Item;
const {TextArea}= Input


class Topic extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                topic: {},
                comment: {
                    text:''
                }
            };


     this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     this.isFormInvalid=this.isFormInvalid.bind(this);
     this.handleCommentChange=this.handleCommentChange.bind(this);
     //this.listTopicWithComments=this.listTopicWithComments.bind(this);
} 
     handleSubmit(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         const commentData= this.state.comment.text;
         const commentTopicid= this.state.topic.id;
         console.log("commentdata:", commentData);
         console.log("topicid: ", commentTopicid);

         createComment(commentData,commentTopicid)
         .then(response => {
             console.log("response comment: ", response.data);
             this.props.history.push("/");
         }).catch(error => {
             if(error.status === 401){
                 this.props.handleLogout('/login', 'error', 'You have been logged out. Please login and choose randome topic.');
             }else {
                 notification.error({
                     message: 'Social-J App',
                     description: error.message || 'Sorry, something went wrong.'
                 });
             }
         });
         listTopicWithComments(commentTopicid)
         .then(response => {
             console.log("topic comment", response.data);
             this.props.history.push("/");
         });


     }

      validateComment = (commentText) => {
            if(commentText.length === 0) {
                return {
                    validateStatus: 'error',
                    errorMsg: 'Please enter your comment!'
                }
            } else if (commentText.length > 150) {
                return {
                    validateStatus: 'error',
                    errorMsg: `Comment is too long (Maximum 150 characters allowed)`
                }    
            } else {
                return {
                    validateStatus: 'success',
                    errorMsg: null
                }
            }
        }

     handleCommentChange(event) {
            const value = event.target.value;
            this.setState({
                comment: {
                    text: value,
                     ...this.validateComment(value)
                }
            });
        }


            componentDidMount(){
                if(this.props.isAuthenticated){
                axios.get(URL)
                .then((response) => 
                {
                    console.log("response", response.data);
                    this.setState({topic:response.data})
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });

            }
        }

            isFormInvalid() {
                if(this.state.comment.validateStatus !== 'success') {
                    return true;
                }

               }



     render() {
         //console.log("URL used: ",URL);
        //console.log("new topic",this.state.topic.id);
        //console.log("new topic",this.state.topic.topic);

        const topicId = this.state.topic.id;
        const uDate = this.state.topic.expirationDateTime;
        const oldComments=this.state.topic.comments;
            console.log("topicid: ", topicId);
         console.log("date: ", uDate);
         console.log("oldcomments: ", oldComments );




            //return nComment;
             return (

                     <div className="new-comment-container">
                     <h1 className="page-title">{this.state.topic.topic}</h1>
                     <div>
                        {this.state.topic.comments.map(comment =>{
                            return <div key={comment.id}>
                            {comment.comment}
                    </div>
                        })}


                        </div>
                         <div className="new-comment-content">

                         <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="create-comment-form">
                            <FormItem validateStatus={this.state.comment.validateStatus}
                            help={this.state.comment.errorMsg} className="comment-form-row">
                            <TextArea placeholder="Enter comment" style={{ fontSize: '16px'}}
                            autosize={{minRows:3, maxRows: 6}}
                            name="comment"
                            value={this.state.comment.text}
                            onChange={this.handleCommentChange} /></FormItem>
                            <FormItem className="comment-form-row">
                            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" size="large"
                                disabled={this.isFormInvalid()}
                            className="create-comment-form-button">Add Comment</Button>
                            </FormItem>
                            </Form>
                         </div>
                         <div>
                         hi

                         </div>
                         </div>
             )}
    }
    export default withRouter(Topic);
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: this.state.topic.comments is undefined
render
client/src/components/Topic.js:134

  131 |  <div className="new-comment-container">
  132 |  <h1 className="page-title">{this.state.topic.topic}</h1>
  133 |  <div>
> 134 |     {this.state.topic.comments.map(comment =>{
  135 |         return <div key={comment.id}>
  136 |         {comment.comment}
  137 | </div>
```

Comment: Where would you expect `this.state.topic.comments` to be populated?

Comment: The comments are an array object that are in the topic object. I want to get comments from the topic object and render them. @OliverRadini

Answer (score 0):

That's because the variable this.state.topic.comments has no values

Comment: There are values in the database. I want to get them and render them. @koFTT